# What damage or reduced performance would result from giving 120 V, 60 Hz AC power to a 115 V, 400 Hz AC/DC rectifier?

Tags: rectifier, ac-dc, reverse-engineering

This is part of a larger project, and is one sub-question related to a higher-level question I've asked on [Reverse Engineering](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/31742/determining-power-supply-needs-for-a-first-class-reclining-airplane-seat?noredirect=1#comment47870_31742). You may find useful background information there.

I have a controller for a powered reclining seat with two physical components (i.e., two boxes). The original power input to this recliner was 115 V, 400 Hz AC power, either single phase or 3-phase; both might have been available to the device originally, but I'm not sure which it would have used. This external power supply was connected to the smaller of these seat boxes, and there is a 2-conductor cable that goes from the smaller box to the larger one. I have not yet been successful in removing either box from the seat, nor have I been able to open either box (such as, to look for information printed on the PCB).

Based on the seat position motors in the recliner, I've concluded that they were run on DC power in the range 24 V to 29 V, though I'm not sure precisely what level within this range. All the seat motors are connected to the second, larger underseat box. The control pads for the recliner are also connected to this second box, and it appears that two 12 V LED reading lights were also powered from this second box.

Given this situation, I'm guessing that the first box, which received the 115 V, 400 Hz input power, was just a rectifier that converted this AC source to a DC source that was provided to the second box, and that the second box was the seat controller (and maybe stepped its DC power down to 12 V for the reading lights).

I'd like to power this recliner from 120 V 60 Hz wall power. Rather than find a converter that will raise the 120 V, 60 Hz wall source to 115 V, 400 Hz that this recliner calls for, with my hypothesis of how the system functioned, I believe I can do this by replacing the first box (hypothetically just a rectifier) and providing the appropriate DC voltage to the second box. However, I don't know precisely what DC voltage the second box would take in, and I don't know which of the conductors in the power supply cable is positive and which is ground.

**If I remove the small box (hypothetically the original rectifier in the recliner) and provide wall power (120 V, 60 Hz) to it, is it likely to produce the appropriate output voltage so that I can measure it? (...and so that I can determine the appropriate conductors in the power supply cable, with the goal of replacing the original power supply.) Or am I likelier to damage something, or get no usable data, by temporarily giving it the wrong power source?**

Comment: 400 Hz is used in aeroplanes. If that's an aeroplane seat, why would it work at 60 Hz if it is designed to work at 400 Hz only? The transformers may saturate as the frequency is much less and any capacitors on the input might be too small for 60 Hz fthey are expecting to get 400 Hz.

Comment: If this uses a transformer, designed for 400 Hz, it will saturate on 60 Hz. Try reading the resistance of the power connection. If it reads just a few ohms, that indicates a transformer. If it reads an increasing resistance, and eventually close to open circuit, it indicates a diode bridge and capacitors, which may work well enough with 60 Hz.

Comment: @PStechPaul, I tried reading the resistance across the AC power input. You can see a photo of the power connector [here](https://github.com/euangeleo/aircraft-seat/blob/main/media/231-PGA-power-backside.jpg). There are 7 pins on the connector. Pins 2 to 4 shows 144 Ohms, and pins 3 to 6 shows 0.5 Ohms, neither of which changes with time. From your description, that seems consistent with the box using a transformer, so it would likely *not* read a proper output voltage if I feed it 60Hz, yes?

I don't know if it will help, but the manufacture date of the seats is listed as 01/2007.

Comment: There is no way to safely determine which pins are for the 120 V 400 Hz inputs. If the two pins showing 0.5 ohms are a transformer primary, you might be able to apply a current limited 60 Hz voltage up to about 15-20 volts, and you might then detect a DC voltage on the output pins. But if it is more than a simple rectifier and capacitor supply, this would probably not work. If you have a VFD, it may be able to produce 400 Hz at 120 VAC to run the system as intended. But it would be best to open the box to see what's actually in it.

Comment: You might be able to find aircraft power plugs that have the same pin configuration as your device, but what I found are some rectangular connectors. https://aircraftplugs.com/product/400hz-115v-ground-power-connector-ms25486/ The following equipment looks similar to what you have: https://www.astronics.com/advanced-electronic-systems/in-seat-power-supply/

Comment: @PSTechPaul, thanks for links to plugs & power supplies. The *plugs* are GX12-7 pin, which I've found online. The Astronics power supply that you linked to is not what I'm referring to in this question; there *is* an [Astronics power supply box](https://github.com/euangeleo/aircraft-seat/blob/main/media/200-Astronics-label.jpg) in the seats, but it powers two 110V60Hz outlets on the front of the seats. The ECU power supply which is what this question is about is for an older version of [this](https://www.astronics.com/docs/default-source/documents-pga/motion/gen-vii-ecu.pdf?sfvrsn=aa25a158_2).

Comment: I found a source for the connectors, but they don't seem to have any standard for what connects to the pins. https://renhotecpro.com/product-category/gx-aviation-connector Your best bet will probably be contacting Astronics. Then we might discuss ways to provide the 120 VAC 400 Hz. A VFD might do the job for about $100, or it could be a challenging project to design and build a supply. There are many designs for 60 Hz inverters, and it should be easy to convert to 400 Hz.

Comment: Here are some ideas for obtaining the 400 Hz supply: https://www.powerstream.com/400hz-tutorial.htm  -  https://www.researchgate.net/publication/341247702_Design_and_Simulation_of_a_Single-Phase_400_Hz_Inverter_with_Variable_Input_and_Output_Voltages - https://www.homemade-circuits.com/7-simple-inverter-circuits/ -- If you decide to build a 400 Hz inverter, please post that as a new question. It could be an interesting project, and seems not too complicated, if your device will accept a simple square wave or "modified sine". True sine would be more challenging. :)

Comment: @PStechPaul, thanks for all the suggestions. I did write to PGA Electronics (the makers of this power supply and electronic control unit for the seat) on 4/19, but have not gotten a response yet. I'm not optimistic that I will; I'm one person who has one of their products that was retired & salvaged and isn't going to buy something directly from them.

As a cheaper/faster way to get a power connector (which, I should correct, appears to be a GX20, not GX12) there are several airports near here that process salvaged aircraft, so I may try one of them, as well.

Answer (score 2):

Try the manufacturer to provide the documentation for the item.  Since it runs on 115V@ 400 Hz AC, I gather this isn't cheap Cheese junk, and is some sort of aerospace-tier specialty item, which are freakishly well-supported.

It is rather unlikely that this is an adaptation of a home recliner. Aerospace has to be designed from the ground up for aviation, and it would be less difficult to scratchbuild a recline mechanism than try to improve and certify a random home recliner that is optimized for cheapness.  Even if you did, the OE manufacturer might discontinue it and then your parts supply would be gone.

Larger aircraft use 115VAC / 400 Hz power for higher power applications around the airplane.  Simpler airplanes use "28 volts" which actually means a 12-cell lead-acid battery, basically two car batteries in series, and it would not surprise me to see aviation equipment built internally for 28 volts with an adapter to let it run off 115VAC/400Hz.  That would allow it to be used on more platforms.

If common recliners use that too, that's wild coincidence.

> However, I don't know precisely what DC voltage the second box would take in, and I don't know which of the conductors in the power supply cable is positive and which is ground.

That's what the manufacturer should be able to tell you.

While I agree with AnalogKid's concerns, you can probably power the supply *momentarily* for testing, or open-circuit, and you certainly can and probably should attempt a teardown to see how it's built and what it does.

Comment: Strangely, I have had a *very* hard time finding documentation about these things online! They are seats that were salvaged from a 767--so, not cheap junk, but definitely a bit old.

Comment: @EricJackson What's strange about that? All the best stuff is "not online" lol.    If it was easy, everyone would do it!

Answer (score 1):

The input frequency is almost three octaves below the design intent.  After whatever is doing the rectification, the ripple voltage across the filter capacitors will be significantly greater than with a 400 Hz source.  Two problems.

1. The ripple current through the filter capacitors also will be significantly greater, possibly exceeding the current rating for the caps.  Even if the caps are rated for the current, they will be running much closer to their limits.  This will increase internal heating and shorten their lifetime.
2. While the peak voltage across the caps might be almost identical to that with a 400 Hz source, the negative peaks of the ripple voltage will be much lower.  They might be so low that a downstream voltage regulator pulls out of regulation because its minimum input-output differential voltage is not being met.  Besides fluttering power to the circuits, the regulator's output impedance will shoot up, disrupting some circuits even if they can handle the fluttering.

Separate from that, if anything in the circuits relies on a 400 Hz signal for operation, it will not be happy.